# How to handle events in pure functional React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

According to [Cam Jackson](https://camjackson.net/post/9-things-every-reactjs-beginner-should-know), we should use Redux, and write small, stateless, functional components. Here's an example:

```
const ListView = ({items}) => (
    <ul>
        {items.map(item => <ItemView item={item}/>)}
    </ul>
)

const ItemView = ({item}) => (
    <li><a>{item.name}</a></li>
)
```

Now, say that you want to handle mouse clicks, and trigger an action that takes the item that was clicked. I think this is a pretty nice way to do this:

```
const ListView = ({items, onItemClicked}) => {
    const _onClick = item => event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        onItemClicked(item)
    }
    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map(item => <ItemView item={item} onClick={_onClick(item)}/>)}
        </ul>
    )
}

const ItemView = ({item, onClick}) => (
    <li><a onClick={onClick}>{item.name}</a></li>
)
```

However, according to [Esa-Matti Suuronen](https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f#.5y14lemv2), this is an anti-pattern that will cause a performance penalty.

Obviously, it's possible to handle the event inside the `ItemView` component, and inject `item`. But, if we want to avoid creating functions inside render functions, then we need to make it a class component.

This is a very common pattern, and I want to find a simple way to handle this, with functional components, without causing performance problems. What do you suggest?

If there is no way to do this, I won't be able to use functional components at all. Because I think more often than not, at some point I will need to convert every functional component to a class.

Comment: You could just move `_onClick` outside of the function - that way, it'd still be in scope, but it wouldn't get reinitialized every time the component renders. That said, at that point it might just be cleaner to turn it into a class.

Comment: No. You're missing the point. First of all, you can't do that because it's referencing the `onItemClicked` prop. Of course you can pass it in. But the point is that it creates a new _bound_ function each time. Notice that `_onClick` is a function that returns a function (I guess it's called a higher order function). Since `ItemView` gets a new prop each time, this will break "pure rendering" optimizations. The question is if there is a way to make this work without using classes.

Comment: Apologies, I shouldn't have commented before having my morning coffee! I'm not sure of the solution, in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more thinking, I think I've found the way to do it. I realize that we need to have more Redux containers. Not only for main top-level components, but also for reusable child components.

The example above can be solved like this:

```
const ListView = ({items, onItemClicked}) => (
    <ul>
        {items.map(item => <ItemContainer item={item} onItemClicked={onItemClicked}/>)}
    </ul>
)

const ItemView = ({item, onClick}) => (
    <li><a onClick={onClick}>{item.name}</a></li>
)

const mapDispatch = (dispatch, {item, onItemClicked}) => ({
    onClick: (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        onItemClicked(item)
    }
})

const ItemContainer = connect(null, mapDispatch)(ItemView)
```

In many cases, we will not need to pass a callback from the outer component to the inner, because we will be able to dispatch the action directly from the `ItemContainer`.

Comment: Doesn't this have the same problem? Every time mapDispatch is called, a new function is passed in to the onClick property.

Comment: `mapDispatch` is called everytime the component receives new props (`item` in this case, assuming `onItemClicked` doesn't change). In this case, we expect the component to re-render, because it represents a new item. In the original example, _all_ `ItemView` would be re-rendered every time any single item was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `onItemClicked` function as a prop on `ItemView` and use that as the `onClick` function.  In the implementation of `onItemClicked` have it receive an event, and get the `item` off of the event.

```
<ItemView item={item} onItemClicked={onItemClicked}/>

const ItemView = ({item, onItemClicked}) => (
    <li><a item={item} onClick={onItemClicked}>{item.name}</a></li>
)
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't actually answer the question of how to get the item off of the event.

Comment: const item = event.target.item

Comment: That doesn't work, you get this error: _Unknown prop `item` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element_

However, it is possible to store a reference in the DOM as a data attribute, e.g. `data-item={item.id}`. It is in fact what we have been doing. It only support strings, so you can only store something like an ID, or serialize the data as JSON. I don't like this solution very much.